# android emulator does not load my application

Tags: android

I am new to Android developement and it is taking forever to resolve my first encountered problem.. The emulator keeps showing me a dialog saying "Process system is not responding. Do you want to close it?[Wait/ok]". My question is does the dialog have anything to do with why my application does not load on the android emulator?

Comment: try running emulator first, if its launches successfully then problem its related to your App. One more thing if you have a android phone test on it, it will save you a ton of time

Comment: I'm using netbeans IDE and the program is the simple hello world program. Followed the instructions creating the project. I didn't edit anything

Comment: Hey, yes you are right. The problem was from my app. Netbeans IDE didn't include the <uses-sdk/> tag in the manifest file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

Close the Eclipse if running
Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in Command Prompt
type adb kill-server (Eclipse should be closed before issuing these commands)
then type adb start-server
No error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then adb is started successfully.
Now you can start Eclipse again.

Restart your emulator as well!

Comment: I got this *daemon not running. Starting it now on port 5037* ADB server didn't ACK *failed to start daemon* while trying to start the server